# How to access SummarRow/Summary Record in a ExtJS 4 Grid with GroupingSummary feature?

Tags: extjs, grid, grouping, extjs4.1

Is there any way to access the summryrow of a particular group while we use groupingsummary inside a Grid (ExtJS  4)?

For example :

[image: Grouping Grid]

Let's say we changed the value of Cement's Qty from 100 to 1000
Purchse value changed to 10000 from 1000 &
Total changed from 51000 to 61000

Now wants to set the Total Purchse 61000 (which is on the tp with groupheaderTpl) for the Group "Manufacturing" when there is summary update for this group.

The question is while editing a cell how can I access the coressponding group's summary so that I can set the value.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using store's [sum function](http://docs.extjs.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sum) with 'grouped' parameter set to true, which will return an object with group name and summary value.

Sample fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dq